# How can I generate SBOM in sub-module and get an aggregated SBOM? Regression with makeAggregateBom since 2.7.4 - outputReactorProjects has no effect

Tags: maven-plugin, owasp, byte-order-mark, cyclonedx

I have a multi module maven project which I'd like to create an SBOM on each module and get an Aggregated BOM on the root-folder with cyclonedx-maven-plugin.

When I execute the following command :

`mvn clean install org.cyclonedx:cyclonedx-maven-plugin:2.7.2:makeAggregateBom -DoutputReactorProjects=true -DoutputFormat=xml -B`

I have an Aggregated BOM on the root target folder and also BOM inside each module. That's the expected behavior.
In some case, if it's needed, I put the property "outputReactorProjects" to false to only get the aggregated bom on the root target folder.

Since 2.7.4, the property "outputReactorProjects" has no effect and I never get the BOM inside the module if I use the "makeAggregateBom" goal. Just like if the property is set to false ( https://cyclonedx.github.io/cyclonedx-maven-plugin/makeAggregateBom-mojo.html#outputReactorProjects )

Following documenation we can still produced an Aggregated BOM and a BOM inside the sub-module :
*"makeAggregateBom: creates an aggregate BOM at build root (with dependencies from the whole multi-modules build), and eventually a BOM for each module"*

Case reproduced with Maven 3.8.5 and Maven 3.9.0, Plugin version 2.7.4, 2.7.5 and 2.7.9.

I have tried these commands :

mvn clean install org.cyclonedx:cyclonedx-maven-plugin:2.7.2:makeAggregateBom -DoutputReactorProjects=true -DoutputFormat=xml -B

---> Root SBOM and Sub-Modules

mvn clean install org.cyclonedx:cyclonedx-maven-plugin:2.7.2:makeAggregateBom -DoutputReactorProjects=false -DoutputFormat=xml -B

---> Root SBOM only

mvn clean install org.cyclonedx:cyclonedx-maven-plugin:2.7.4:makeAggregateBom -DoutputReactorProjects=true -DoutputFormat=xml -B

---> Root SBOM only

mvn clean install org.cyclonedx:cyclonedx-maven-plugin:2.7.4:makeAggregateBom -DoutputReactorProjects=false -DoutputFormat=xml -B

---> Root SBOM only

mvn clean install org.cyclonedx:cyclonedx-maven-plugin:2.7.9:makeAggregateBom -DoutputReactorProjects=true -DoutputFormat=xml -B

---> Root SBOM only

mvn clean install org.cyclonedx:cyclonedx-maven-plugin:2.7.9:makeAggregateBom -DoutputReactorProjects=false -DoutputFormat=xml -B